# Is Prokofiev's Suggestion Diabolique an etude?

Tags: piano

I am playing Prokofiev's Suggestion Diaboliqe (the real translation of the title of the piece would be Obbsesion). Does anybody know the backround of this piece and was it supposed to be an etude? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The piece comes from a collection, *4 Pieces for Piano*, op. 4. The pieces are student works, originally written in 1908, when Prokofiev was 16 or 17, then revised, before being published in 1913. They are character pieces, and not intended as etudes.

Comment: Thank you. I was asking for that because I am going to a competition in which you have to play 1 etude so I tought this piece might come wright.